# Serializing a class to XML including attributes?

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

If I have a class with attributes on it's properties and want to serialize the class to XML, is it possible to include these attributes in the generated XML?

For Instance:

```
<SomeClassAttribute()> _
Public Class MyClass

private m_Property1 as string

<SomePropertyAttribute()> _
public Property1 as string
get
  return m_Property1 as string
end get
set(ByVal Value as string)
  m_Property1 = value
end set
end property

end Class
```

Comment: Why? Do you need to XML to fit a specified format?

Comment: I just need to capture the class attribute data in the xml if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, basically. Unless you expose a *regular* property that provides them, or implement `IXmlSerializable`. The intent of serialization is to serialize an ***individual object's*** properties; attributes are metadata annotations, that are not really associated with any *specific* instance. As such, they don't *naturally* fit into object serialization, except perhaps (as metadata) to *guide* it (for example `[XmlTypeAttribute]`, `[XmlRootAttribute]`, etc)